# Is there a way to move the blpapi from Python environment to the Ananconda environment?

Tags: python, path, blpapi

I have successfully installed the blpapi module, but I installed it in the Python38-32 directory. Therefore I am not able to import it from a script BBG_API contained in "C:\Users\33769\Anaconda3".

I have the following set up on pycharm : [image]

[image]

I have tried the following code but it returns "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blpapi'" :

```
import numpy as np
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Users/33769/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/site-packages/blpapi")
import blpapi
import sys
```

Should I need to copy or move or install the directory "blpapi" in the folder "C:\Users\33769\Anaconda3" ?

Thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise installing with `conda` instead of pip. You can do this via

`conda install -c conda-forge blpapi`

Comment: I did it this way and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad it worked, feel free to accept this answer.